# Change Font Color of a Column in a DataGridView Control (C# winforms)

Tags: c#

I have a `DataGridView` control with two columns. The default color of the text is black. Is it possible to set the fore color of the entire second row to gray?(or any other color)..

```
    COLUMN1 | COLUMN2
    -----------------
     black  | gray
     black  | gray
     black  | gray
```

Please help.. thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your subject and question are confusing, one refers to the column and one to the rows but anyway.

```
grid.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

should handle the column color.

```
grid.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

should handle the row color.

Comment: How about if i want to set the entire column2 as Bold?

Comment: Have a look at the other properties on DefaultCellStyle it's not hard to figure out.

Comment: Or if you are using a WebControl GridView you can set the CSS style, which allows you to control many things, including the text color

Answer (score 2):

```cs
dgv.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

or `Columns[1]`, if that's what you meant.